# React Redux SSR how to suppress initial actions called from componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, serverside-javascript

I was able to preload all the needed states in the server-side and pass these initial states to the client application's redux store.

I have enabled redux-logger to see what happens in my application and the states are being refetched from the store. That's. because my components call the the necessary action during `componentDidMount`. Here is an example reducer, action and component:

```
// action:
import axios from 'axios';

export function fetchNewsTop() {
    return {
        type: 'FETCH_NEWS_TOP',
        payload: axios.get('/news/top')
    };
}

// reducer:
export function newsArchive(state = {
    pending: false,
    response: { data: [] },
    error: null
}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_NEWS_TOP_PENDING':
        return { ...state, pending: true, response: { data: [] }, error: null };
    case 'FETCH_NEWS_TOP_FULFILLED':
        return { ...state, pending: false, response: action.payload.data, error: null };
    case 'FETCH_NEWS_TOP_REJECTED':
        return { ...state, pending: false, response: { data: [] }, error: action.payload };
    default:
        return state;
    }
}

// component:
export class NewsArchiveFactory extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchNewsTop();
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.news) {
            return (
                <NewsGrid items={this.props.news} />
            );
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am using `redux-promise-middleware`, which creates the promise actions (fulfilled, rejected, pending).

The action gets called when component is mounted. My understanding is that componentDidMount gets called even if the component is rendered in server-side to inform the JS that it exists. The component itself doesn't get remounted. However, I have also read that it is a better choice to run my actions in `componentDidMount` and I personally think that it will not even work if I call it from `componentDidUpdate` (we will enter an infinite loop).

I want to suppress these initial **actions** from getting called because the state is already coming from the server-side. How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47015661/prevent-componentdidmount-from-fetching-data-if-already-available-from-server-si/47019842#47019842

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping there is a better way out there, but so far what I have come up with is to set a `ssr` flag in the reducer state upon receiving data based on whether the data is received on the server or the client.

First, `ComponentDidMount` does not fire on the server, only on the client.  So you will need another mechanism that uses something like the `react-router` match function along with static data fetching functions in your components.  See [universal-react](https://github.com/DominicTobias/universal-react) for a good boilerplate that has an easy-to-understand server-side data fetching mechanism.  However, you will still need to fetch data in your `ComponentDidMount` methods as well or things will break if the Component is only rendered on the client or is mounted later after the initial server render.  This is what introduces the problem of potential "double fetches" when data is pre-loaded on the server but then gets requested again when `ComponentDidMount` fires on the client.

Below is an example implementation that works around this issue (note that I'm using a redux format where actions and reducers are in one file):

redux/modules/app.js:

```js
import { basepath, fetcher, fetchNeeded, checkStatus } from '../../lib/api'

const isClient = typeof document !== 'undefined'

const SET_FLAG_SSR =            'app/SET_FLAG_SSR'
const REQUEST_DATA =            'app/REQUEST_DATA'
const RECEIVE_DATA =            'app/RECEIVE_DATA'
const DATA_FAIL =               'app/DATA_FAIL'
const INVALIDATE_DATA =         'app/INVALIDATE_DATA'

const initialState = {
  ssr: false,
  initialized: false,
  isFetching: false,
  didInvalidate: true,
  conditionFail: false,
  data: {}
}

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_FLAG_SSR:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        ssr: action.flag
      })
    case INVALIDATE_DATA:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        didInvalidate: true
      })
    case REQUEST_DATA:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: true,
        conditionFail: false,
      })
    case RECEIVE_DATA:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        ssr: !isClient,
        initialized: true,
        isFetching: false,
        conditionFail: false,
        didInvalidate: false,
        lastUpdated: action.receivedAt,
        data: action.data,
      })
    case DATA_FAIL:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        conditionFail: true,
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}

function setFlagSSR(flag) {
  return {
    type: SET_FLAG_SSR,
    flag: flag,
  }
}

function requestData() {
  return {
    type: REQUEST_DATA
  }
}

function receiveData(json) {
  return {
    type: RECEIVE_DATA,
    data: json,
    receivedAt: Date.now()
  }
}

function receiveFail(err) {
  return {
    type: DATA_FAIL,
    err: err,
  }
}

function fetchData(url) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(requestData())
    return fetcher(url, { credentials: 'include' }, getState().cookie)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((json) => { return dispatch(receiveData(json)) })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch(receiveFail(err))
    })
  }
}

export function getData() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState()
    if (fetchNeeded(state.app, () => dispatch(setFlagSSR(false)))) {
      return dispatch(fetchData(basepath + '/api/app'))
    }
  }
}
```

lib/api.js:

```js
import fetchPonyfill from 'fetch-ponyfill'
import Promise from 'bluebird'

const { fetch, Request, Response, Headers } = fetchPonyfill(Promise)

const isClient = typeof document !== 'undefined'
export const basepath = isClient ? '': `${__APIROOT__}`

// check HTTP response status and throw error if not valid
export function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response
  } else {
    let error = new Error(response.statusText)
    error.response = response
    throw error
  }
}

// Generic Redux check to triage fetch requests and SSR flags
export function fetchNeeded(statebranch, clearFlagSSR) {
  if (statebranch.isFetching) return false
  if (statebranch.ssr && isClient) {
    clearFlagSSR()
    return false
  }
  return true
}

// Fetch wrapper to set defaults and inject cookie data on server (if present)
export function fetcher(url, config={}, cookie={}) {
  let options = {}
  let headers = new Headers();

  // Base Headers
  headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
  headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  if (config.headers) {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(config.headers).forEach(function(key, idx, array) {
      headers.append(key, config.headers[key])
    })
  }

  if (cookie.value && !isClient) {
    //inject cookie data into options header for server-to-server requests
    headers.set('Cookie', cookie.value)
  }

  options = {
    credentials: config.credentials || 'same-origin',
    method: config.method || 'get',
    headers: headers,
  }

  if (config.body) options.body = config.body

  return fetch(url, options)
}
```

The basics of how this works is that the `ssr` flag in the redux state is set to `true` if the `RECEIVE_DATA` action occurs on the server.  Otherwise it is set to `false`.

If the `getData` function is called on the client, it first calls the `fetchNeeded` function (passing it this particular slice of the state tree along with a function that can dispatch an action to clear the `ssr` flag).  If the `ssr` flag is `true` (and of course we are on the client) the `fetchNeeded` function will return `false` after calling the function to clear the `ssr` flag.

So in the end, if the server called our `getData` function and data is already present then the client won't re-request the data from the server the first time (but instead clear the `ssr` flag).  After the flag has been cleared (or if it was never set in the first place) the client will request data from the server like normal.  This allows us to avoid an initial redundant call for data but still works if a component is only mounted on the client or gets refreshed on the client.

Hopefully that is helpful.