# Prevent componentDidMount from fetching data if already available from server-side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

ComponentDidMount() is triggered when the component is mounted, including when it is hydrated following server-side rendering.

One of the solutions I found online is checking whether we have data in the state; however this requires a lot of code to include on every component. What are other solutions?

```
  componentDidMount() {
    // if rendered initially, we already have data from the server
    // but when navigated to in the client, we need to fetch
    if (!this.state.data) {
      this.constructor.fetchData(this.props.match).then(data => {
        this.setState({ data })
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't think there is another solution. As alternative you can check redux-saga and their selectors

Answer (score 1):

I have found an alternative solution. In my Redux store I keep the URL of the current page. Therefore on navigation, I am able to do the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { url, match } = this.props;
  if (url !== match.url) {
    fetchData(match.path);
  }
}
```

Comment: Wont this make api calls even when data is already available?

Comment: This will make the api call from the server (code not included) and then on the first load it would not because the above condition is false. When navigating to another page, the above condition becomes true and it fetches the data.

Comment: Demo project (WIP): https://github.com/IncredibleWeb/React-PWA-Boilerplate

Comment: A more profound solution would be to fetch the data and store it in redux so that you can reduce api calls and reduce the server load.

Comment: That is what I am doing. But I need the content to he refetched on navigation to prevent it becoming stake. Imagine a news article container for example.

Comment: I guess it is a web app and i would recommed using service worker or api caching. Though the calls will remain as mentioned by you but they will reduce the load on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a boolean variable in the store, I just use one called "done", when the server fetch the data it set the variable to true, in the component in compoponentDidMount just check if the variable is true, if is, then dont fetch the data, like this:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  if(!this.props.done)
    this.props.fetchData();
}
```

Comment: If the same component is used in different scenarios and is expected to retrieve different data then a Boolean `done` would not be enough, which is why I am using URL, as the data retrieved is dependent on the URL.

Comment: I haven't be in that scenario, so I believe you :)